# SharePoint users forwarding emails

Tags: office-365

I am setting up Mail users for external companies so that they can log into SharePoint sites that I am developing. I need to setup forwarding so that if someone sends them an email it will go to their companies email and get notifications from their SharePoint site. When I go in and edit the them there is no option to forward to an external email. I any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is in Office 365, why don't you just invite them with their own live-id's?

Comment: Well it makes more sense for us to manage the user accounts centrally within our system . At least from a permissions standpoint. Each customer will have their own site but we don't want them to be able to access any other site but their own. Also it make sense to use our own logins for them so that I can do permissions testing. @RobertLindgren Lindgren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out by going into the email address section of the mail user and changed the outside email address to the forwarding address and it worked. Thanks for all the suggestions!